# Laravel, Post parameters with redirect

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm trying to do a redirection from my Website to a Wordpress.
I need to Post parameters to this Wordpress to be logged.

Actually I do a redirection to a view like this :

```
return view('admin/redirect', compact('res'));
```

And on this view, I auto submit a Post Form like this :

```
<form class="display-inline" id="dateForm" method="post" action="http://website.com/wp-login.php" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="log" value="{{ $res['log'] }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="pwd" value="{{ $res['pwd'] }}">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('dateForm').submit();
</script>
```

Can someone help me to do this redirection only with PHP (Laravel).
I really try lot of method but nothing work...

Thank's

Comment: Why don't you just do a curl/guzzle post request instead of redirecting to a view that just submits a form? Skip a step and make less shady for your users.

Comment: curl/guzzle do the request on the serveur. I need to log the client not the serveur.